# Decrypt ContactIdentifier in EXM Preference center

Tags: exm

We are trying to customize the EXM preference centre by calling an additional AJAX in the *Preference Center Java Script*

For this we have created a controller action:

```
public class EXMPreferencesController: Controller
{
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getcontact(object Preferences, string EncryptedContactIdentifier)
        {
            // some code
            return Json("ok");
        }
}
```

and appended the below AJAX in `submitPreferences` function in javascript. So that this AJAX will hit on click of the *Update subscription* button on the *Email Preference Center* page.

```
$.ajax('/api/sitecore/EXMPreferences/getcontact', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    processData: false,
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "Preferences" : preferences,
                        "EncryptedContactIdentifier": contactIdentifier
                    })
                }).then(formSuccess, formFail);
```

[image]
AJAX is getting triggered, but how can we get current contact information like contact ID, contact identifier from `EncryptedContactIdentifier` variable in action method.

Any help is much appreciated?

Comment: I think you can get contact ID from the current sitecore context. Otherwise , it is possible to call into sitecore's encryption code to decrypt this - you'll need to find it in dotpeek / ILspy.

Comment: @MarkGibbons Thanks, I think I found a way to decrypt using Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Crypto.IStringCipher class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To decrypt the contact, we'll need to use `cipher.TryDecrypt` method from `Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Crypto` library. This method with return contact identifier. After getting the contact identifier, we will call `ContactService` from `Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Contacts` library to Get the contact. Complete implementation will look like this:

```
public class EXMPreferencesController : Controller
    {
        // Sitecore.XConnect ContactIdentifier
        private ContactIdentifier _contactIdentifier;
        // Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cd.Services IMarketingPreferencesService to get the marketing preferences from preference center page
        private readonly IMarketingPreferencesService _marketingPreferencesService;
        // Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Contacts IContactService to get the contacts from XDB
        private readonly IContactService _contactService;
        // Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Crypto IStringCipher to encrypt or decrypt contacts
        private readonly IStringCipher _cipher;
        private Contact _contact;
 
        public EXMPreferencesController()
        {
            // To get the contactService from current sitecore context using Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator
            IContactService contactService = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IContactService>();
            // To get the cipher from current sitecore context using Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator
            IStringCipher cipher = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<IStringCipher>();
            // check cipher and contactService should not be null
            Condition.Requires<IContactService>(contactService, nameof(contactService)).IsNotNull<IContactService>();
            Condition.Requires<IStringCipher>(cipher, nameof(cipher)).IsNotNull<IStringCipher>();
            this._contactService = contactService;
            this._cipher = cipher;
        }
 
        // get all the Preferences in List of Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Model.XConnect.Facets.MarketingPreference model
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public void UpdateContactPreferences(List<MarketingPreference> Preferences, string EncryptedContactIdentifier)
        {
            ContactIdentifier contactIdentifier = this.GetContactIdentifier(EncryptedContactIdentifier);
 
            Contact contact = this.GetContact(contactIdentifier);
            
            
// Get xconnect client in sitecore context
            using (Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClient client = Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
            {
                if (contact != null)
                {
                    // write your logic, here we are saving customer preferences to custom facets
                }
                client.Submit();
            }
        }
 
        protected ContactIdentifier GetContactIdentifier(string encryptedValue)
        {
            if (this._contactIdentifier != null)
                return this._contactIdentifier;
            try
            {
                string str = this._cipher.TryDecrypt(encryptedValue);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
                {
 
                    return (ContactIdentifier)null;
                }
                this._contactIdentifier = str.ToContactIdentifier();
                return this._contactIdentifier;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return (ContactIdentifier)null;
            }
        }
        protected Contact GetContact(ContactIdentifier contactIdentifier)
        {
            return this._contact ?? (this._contact = this._contactService.GetContactWithRetry(contactIdentifier, 100.0, 3, this.FacetKeys));
        }
```

Refer to this blog for more details: https://sitecorewithraman.wordpress.com/2022/01/01/customization-of-exm-preference-center-and-decrypt-contacts/